# How do I change the length of the timeline of the composition to only be as long as my video footage?

Tags: after-effects, time

[image]

How do I reduce the length on the Time Ruler in order to make the composition shorter in duration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do what @stib said. Use the B and N shortcuts to set the beginning and end of the work area to match your footage. Another good shortcut is  Shift and X to cut the timeline to the current work area.

Answer (score 1):

There's no built - in function that does it, but there's a script for that. I wrote one called first-n-last, it's available (free, open source) here https://blob.pureandapplied.com.au/

Alternatively, park your playhead at the beginning of the first layer (select that layer and hit <kbd>i</kbd>), then set the start of the work area to that frame by hitting <kbd>b</kbd> then select the last layer and hit go to the last frame (hit <kbd>o</kbd>) and set the end of the work area to that frame by hitting <kbd>n</kbd>. Now right click the work area and choose **trim comp to work area** from the contextual menu. This doesn't work for layers that extend beyond the beginning or end of the comp, but my srcipt does.

Comment: You have a really nice website! I'll try it out and get back.